# How can I send a system response if a user says something? NodeJS/socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to make it so if a user says a specific thing, the socket.io responds with something.

ex.
Input: !hi 
Output: hello!

If there's a way to do this, I would like to know how, thanks!

I tried making something so if a user just presses the send button, it sends "Please type something", it can only be seen by the user typing the space.

```
var spaced = ' ';

if (spaced) {
  socket.emit('message', {
        username: 'System',
        text: 'Please Type Something',
        timestamp: moment().valueOf()
    });
}
```

server.js:

```
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var moment = require('moment');
var connectedUsers = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  
  /*var socketId = socket.id;
  var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;

    console.log('A user is connected. - IP: ' + clientIp + " | ID: " + socketId);*/
  console.log('A user is connected.')

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        var userData = connectedUsers[socket.id];
        if (typeof userData !== 'undefined') {
            socket.leave(connectedUsers[socket.id]);
            io.to(userData.room).emit('message', {
                username: 'System',
                text: userData.username + ' has left!',
                timestamp: moment().valueOf()
            });
            delete connectedUsers[socket.id];
        }
    });

    socket.on('joinRoom', function(req, callback) {
        if (req.room.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0 && req.username.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0) {
            var nameTaken = false;

            Object.keys(connectedUsers).forEach(function(socketId) {
                var userInfo = connectedUsers[socketId];
                if (userInfo.username.toUpperCase() === req.username.toUpperCase()) {
                    nameTaken = true;
                }
            });

            if (nameTaken) {
                callback({
                    nameAvailable: false,
                    error: 'This username is taken, please choose another one.'
                });
            } else {
                connectedUsers[socket.id] = req;
                socket.join(req.room);
                socket.broadcast.to(req.room).emit('message', {
                    username: 'System',
                    text: req.username + ' has joined!',
                    timestamp: moment().valueOf()
                });
                callback({
                    nameAvailable: true
                });
            }
        } else {
            callback({
                nameAvailable: false,
                error: 'Please complete the forum.'
            });
        }
    });

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        message.timestamp = moment().valueOf();
        io.to(connectedUsers[socket.id].room).emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.emit('message', {
        username: 'System',
        text: 'Ask someone to join this chat room to start talking.',
        timestamp: moment().valueOf()
    });

});

http.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + PORT);
});
```

The body in my index.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login-area">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-7 medium-7 small-12 columns small-centered">
            <form id="login-form">
              <h2>Twintails Bot Chatroom</h2>
              <p id="error-msg"></p>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Enter your username"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="room"
                placeholder="Enter a chat room name"
              />
              <input type="submit" value="Join Chat" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="message-area">
        <div class="large-8 columns small-centered">
          <h2>Twintails Bot Chatroom</h2>
          <div class="chat-wrap">
            <div class="top">
              <h5 class="room-title"></h5>
            </div>
            <div id="messages"></div>
            <form id="message-form">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Type message here"
                  class="input-group-field"
                  name="message"
                />
                <div class="input-group-button">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>
          Add the
          <a href="https://twintails-bot-dashboard.glitch.me/" target="_blank"
            >Twintails bot!</a
          >
        </p>
        <p>
          Use the 'Mod' room to talk to mods!
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/socket.io-1.7.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please show a more complete code example on both client and server and add to your explanation as it's not yet clear what you're trying to accomplish.  It is easy to examine an incoming message and decide what to send back (if anything).  Also, when you say "user says something", what does that mean exactly?  Is that an incoming socket.io message or are you talking about says something into the speaker on the client?

Comment: When I say "user says something" I mean the person actually chatting. I want someone to write a specific thing, and when they write that specific thing in the chat, it responds with something. I updated my code btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're talking about is when the server receives a specific typed message, you want to send a specific response directly back to the user who typed that message, you can just do something like this:

```
// this is your existing server-side handler which the `if` statement added to it
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.text === '!hi') {
        socket.emit('message', {
            username: 'System',
            text: 'hello!',
            timestamp: moment().valueOf()
        });
    } else {
        message.timestamp = moment().valueOf();
        io.to(connectedUsers[socket.id].room).emit('message', message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a simple if statement?

```
if (mySocketData === "!hi") {
    socket.emit('Hello!');
}
```

*New to Socket.IO, not sure if this helps, sorry!*

Comment: That's kinda a dumb answer, I've never used Socket.IO, so it's **clearly** a placeholder.